# Chrome extension: String comparison in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome-extension, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings using JavaScript, and I am honestly stumped as to why this is not working for me. I've tried using ==, ===, localeCompare(), adding spaces, converting it to lowercase, and nothing is working! Here is my code (from my content script)

```
var longBrand = byline.innerHTML;
var brand = longBrand.substring(7);
console.log(brand);

if(brand){
    console.log("It can read inside this statement");
    var lowerBrand = brand.toLowerCase();
    console.log(lowerBrand);
    if(lowerBrand === "nike" || lowerBrand === " nike" || lowerBrand === "  nike"){
        console.log("testing");
    }
}
```

The variable brand comes from a substring of longBrand, which is taken from a webpage. The console shows everything is logged except for the last console.log("testing"); and I can't figure out why that is. Console looks like this:

```
Nike
It can read inside this statement
nike
```

I've even double checked that typeof brand is a string. I don't know what's going wrong here! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works good here. Maybe your variable `brand` isn't "Nike". Try to do:
`brand = brand.trim();` 
to remove white spaces.

```js
// var longBrand = byline.innerHTML;
// var brand = longBrand.substring(7);
const brand = "Nike"

if(brand){
    console.log("It can read inside this statement");
    const lowerBrand = brand.toLowerCase();
    console.log(lowerBrand);
    if(lowerBrand === "nike" || lowerBrand === " nike" || lowerBrand === "  nike"){
        console.log("testing");
    }
}
```

Comment: This must've been my problem -- it's working now! I'm new to JavaScript, so I was unfamiliar with the trim() method. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet lol. Thank you so much!!